# edmonds algorithm for bipartite maximum matching

Tags: bipartite

I want to find the maximum matching in a bipartite matching using edmonds algorithm. Unfortunately I am unable to get the pseudo-code. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you still looking for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a late post for the benefit of future visitors. There is pseudo code available in [wikipidia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm#Bipartite_matching)

> Edmonds Algorithm is applicable to general graphs and not just
>   bipartite graphs. The wiki page shows how the general algorithm can be
>   used for bipartite graphs.